# Power BI: Recreating dashboard by grouping partial information into a dropdown

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have a dashboard in Power BI that looks like this:

| Name | Specified Activity | Level | Activity Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | Basketball | 2 | Sports |
| Anna | Volleyball | 3 | Sports |
| Julie | Basketball | 1 | Sports |
| Julie | Tennis | 2 | Sports |
| Julie | Guitar | 4 | Instrument |
| Julie | Piano | 5 | Instrument |

And I have to group it to look something like this:

| Name | Specified Activity | Activity Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | DROPDOWN | Sports |
| Julie | DROPDOWN | Sports |
| Julie | DROPDOWN | Instrument |

DROPDOWN meaning that if you press it, you can see Name of the Specified activity and its level.
In other words, if you press dropdown (or something similar) you get extra information (for Anna, you get Basketball 2 and Volleyball 3.
To clarify, the same person can appear multiple times but its activity group is different. For example, Julie appeared two times, but activity group is once Sports, other time Instrument.

I tried different things, but don't have an idea how to include dropdown into dashboard (or do something similar to it) and group it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI doesn't work that way.

You have a few options:

- **Drill-through** - select a row, then with a drill-though button, takes you to a new page in the report with the details you want. See [Use report page drillthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/report-drillthrough)
- **Custom tooltip** - hovering over the row shows a custom tooltip with the desired details. See [Extend visuals with report page tooltips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/report-page-tooltips)
- **Cross-highlight** - selecting the row performs a cross-highlight on another visual with the row in context. See [Cross-filter and cross-highlight visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-reports-filters-and-highlighting#cross-filter-and-cross-highlight-visuals)
- **Matrix visual** with multiple rows - see [Expanding and collapsing row headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-matrix-visual#expanding-and-collapsing-row-headers)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hierarchy in one of the columns. A "+" appears and when you click on "+" you can see the information.
Another option is create a drill-through that send you to another page when you click a button(or you can see the information creating a drill-through. After create it, you can see in the right-click menu the option "Drill-Through", that sends you to another page with more information.